# Passing Windows Environmental Variables to Docker - Visual Studio

Tags: docker, visual-studio

I want to avoid hard-coding environmental variables into my launchSettings.json and want some of them to be at a machine level rather than a project level.

I started originally with this:

```
 "DockerfileRunArguments": "-v \"C:\\Oracle\\product\\12.1.0\\client_1\\network\\admin:/root/tns\"",
```

And as an alternative tried to do this:

```
      "DockerfileRunArguments": "-v \"%TNS_ADMIN%:/root/tns\"",
```

I assumed when in Visual Studio it ran through the command line, it would obtain %TNS_ADMIN% and replace it, just as an echo %TNS_ADMIN% is doing from a standard command line.  Really don't want to have this at a project level mapping.